# Get specific value(id) from the url

Tags: c#, string

How to get the id value from the url in c#

```
mp_tcedfew.ut?sys_id=sdsdrtyuy565hh784552fggklopfgeu6&sysparam_view=
```

I need to get the `sdsdrtyuy565hh784552fggklopfgeu6`

Comment: In what context?  Is that just a string you want to parse it from, or are you running in an ASP.NET environment etc etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net

Comment: Depending exactly where you are in your app, you should be able to just use the `Request` object: [See this answer for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18361049/791010)

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid That's the same one it's already been marked a duplicate of?  (And not a great target, given the full context...)

Comment: Oh sorry, page is not updating on my side. problem on my side