# Dynamically adding pages and modifying its URL in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am making a real estate website in APS.NET (web forms) where users can add property listings to the front page, as shown in the screenshot. All information in the listing is retrieved from an mySQL database.

My issue is that I want the user to be able to press "More details" and be redirected to a new page where the full information about the listing is presented. However I don't know how to check which listing was pressed and how to modify the URL of the new page based on the selected listing?

[Screenshot of a property listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXqGo.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a page called `Details.aspx` in VS and use a `QueryString` to pass whichever `PropertyID` (or whatever you use to identify properties) was selected. `Details.aspx` would load details into its controls on `Load`. [Here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360991/how-does-request-querystring-work) regarding `QueryString` and there are many more elsewhere. You would use something like this: `Response.Redirect("~/Details.aspx?pid=" + propertyID);` to pass the ID upon redirection.