# C# HttpListener Request.QueryString UTF-8 Support

Tags: c#

I have a C# Application working with HttpListener. I use get method to store datas and in get method, when i try to store it , utf-8 characterset problem is destroys data.

My code:

```
var context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
string message = context.Request.QueryString["msg"];
```

How can i make it UTF-8 Supported?

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? Can you please post some sample test data / expected result ?
`QueryString` should work independent of the character encoding. It is also likely that your "msg" would be HtmlEncoded.
You can decode using: `HtmlDecode`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx

Also look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360991/how-does-request-querystring-work

Comment: My error is in case of UTF-8 words it writes ????? or smth else but not the same as test data like that :✘✘✘✘✘✘ turns ??????